# Find specific row if text found from external file

Tags: php

I have a file with this content:

```
Line A
Line B
Line C
Line D
Line E
```

If I'm looking for `Line C`, how can I get the result for the row containing `Line C` as `row 2`? I use the `file_get_contents()` syntax as follows:

```
$get_file=file_get_contents("text.txt");
substr_count($get_file, "Line C");
```

but the result is `1`.

Comment: Getting content from text using $get_file=file_get_contents("text.txt"), so i count the row using substr_count($get_file, "Line C"). But the result is showing number one (1).

Answer (score 0):

I tested like this and it return '2'

```
1 <?php
2 $str = "Line A\nLine B\nLine C\nLine D\nLine E\n";
3 $arr = explode("\n", $str);
4 $key = array_search("Line C", $arr);
5 if ($key !== false)
6 {
7     echo $key;
8 }
9 ?>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. i tested like that and return '2'. But, it's impossible for me, cause i am using file_get_contents() for variable $str, not string like above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strstr`](http://php.net/strstr) to get contents before the search string. Using [`substr_count`](http://php.net/substr_count) you can find the occurrence.

```
$search = 'Line C';

$content = file_get_contents('example.txt');

$preceedingContents = strstr($content, $search, true);

if ($preceedingContents !== false) {
    $line = substr_count($preceedingContents, PHP_EOL);
    echo "$search found in row : $line";
} else {
    echo "$search not found";
}
```

Where your `example.txt` contains:

```
Line A
Line B
Line C
Line D
Line E
```

**Gives:**

For, `$search = 'Line C';` gives `Line C found in row : 2` 
For, `$search = 'Line A';` gives `Line C found in row : 0`
For, `$search = 'Line R';` gives `Line R not found`